# Add content to same page drupal 8

Tags: nodes, 8

I got a drupal 8 home page wich works fine but all my content on that page is in the same textbox like this image here:

[image: Example from what i got now]

How can I make it so I can seperate this content and still show it under each other on the home page? This makes it way easier to edit and add new content to the page instead of editing this huge textbox of html code I got now.

I just want it so you can just press the "add content" button and it adds a new html section to the page where you can create a image slider or something and this stacks up under the content that allready  has been added.

If i press the add content now it creates a new node/# page wich I dont want. I just want the content on the home page if i press the add content button there.

Comment: You would need to write that functionality yourself, there's nothing built in to assist with such a non-standard requirement

Comment: How should i start writing this myself? I have no idea where to start

Comment: I can only really say start with the docs - what you want to do is not how Drupal was built, fields are _defined_, not arbitrary. You could create a new multiple field of text areas and add it to a node type, along with inline editing that might work. But it will be text, you can't define a slideshow in it - for that you would need a different field type. But a custom entity type might be more appropriate, too many variables for me to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create "promoted to the front page" nodes and keep `node` as your front page. The "add content" button you wanted is the `node/add` page. This has always worked with Drupal stretching back many years.